# How to import rows from .xlsx and write them in specific places in .docx using Electron?

Tags: javascript, save, electron, docx, xlsx

## Intro

Hi, I was looking for answer in the whole Internet (in some way I kind of feel that I know every question in Stack Overflow), but the answers were never appropriate to what I'm looking for. I was trying to avoid posting question here, but situation forced me to do this. 
Sorry if the answer is simpler than I think.

I'm in the middle of building my first app in Electron using JavaScript. I think that I should describe it in few words, so **flam:ngo™** (which is projects name) should work like this:

1. User will upload two files:

   - file with tables (like XLSX or DOC)
   - file with data and blank spaces (which will be used as a template)
2. App will import from *tables*.
3. Now app should let user choose which rows he's interested in and where in uploaded file he wants them to be placed.
4. flam:ngo save document in PDF (or DOC).

## Clue

Right now I need solutions just for myself and in little simpler form. For now I need flam:ngo just to work with one specify XLSX and with one DOC template, but I stuck. I know which rows in document I will always need, but I don't know what should I write to specify in JS's code that I need exactly this ones (like *hey, app, pick only this one, this one and maybe this one*) while JS is reading file and I don't know how to create new DOC (or PDF) file, how to write data in specified blank spaces and then at the end: how to save it in direction which I should choose for every time I'm using an app - everything in one, maybe two, processes.

## Ending

Could you, please, help me: for now I have implemented file uploader which is importing file in XLSX and which is saving it as CSV, XML oraz HTML. What should I do to keep moving forward?

I really appreciate your help!

PS. For better explanation:

For now this should look like this:

```
1. "template.docx" is uploaded in the core
2. user uploads .xlsx 
3. app reads tables and select rows chosen in code 
4. app puts data from chosen rows in specify places 
5. app saves file > new life of the app :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it's been a while and app has been already written by me. Maybe this will help someone in the future:

## Solution

Packages that helps me with this issue was:

1. [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) which converts my file to simple HTML file, where cells from my XLSX template file have always the same ID (which was important for me to work with document templates).
2. [officegen](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen) which helps me write brand new document based on earlier prepared template.

Rest of it was just Vanilla JS.